# Odoo 14: Onchange only triggering when clicking out of field not while typing

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I have an `onchange` method bound to a field in a form view that looks like this:

```
@api.onchange('name')
    def _onchange_name(self):
           ...
```

I have noticed that this `onchange` is only triggered when clicking outside the field or pressing enter. **It is not triggered while typing** which I would expect from something called "onchange".

I have seen this behaviour in all of `odoo 14`.

Is there a way to trigger an onchange while typing?

Comment: As far as i know: no, not with default Odoo code.

Comment: What would you do to achieve this behaviour, JS callback?

Comment: On many2one fields this is already implemented (async search_name calls). Maybe you can create a new Char widget with such async call functionality? Or maybe there is already something in the community modules. I don't know sorry.

Answer (score 0):

"The @api.onchange will be triggered when one of the given fields is modified in the form view"

When you press on edit button and after that when you modify existing value of field on that time @api.onchange will trigger.

Ex:

```
@api.onchange('field_name')
def method_name(self):
   ... your code.....
```

Comment: This unfortunately not the answer. The normal onchange does not behave the way I liked it too. Have a look at the question again but thank you.